# Cannot upgrade DocumentDB collection (S1 to S2 pricing tier)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to upgrade my DocumentDB collection to get more RU/s.

I tried throught the Azure Portal with two differents browsers (Chrome and Edge).

I keep having an error saying that the Replace Offer Failed with the following JSON error.

```
{"code":400,"body":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Cannot replace an offer with version  with version V1\\r\\nActivityId: <some GUID here>\"}"}
```

[image: Changing documentdb collection pricing tier]

[image: Error changing pricing tier]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benoit, this is indeed a supported scenario. Azure DocumentDB team has identified and mitigated your issue in terms of upgrading your account to S2. Could you please try again?